# How to start a jboss as a service without rebooting the system

Tags: service, batch-file, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm struggling with the start of jboss as a service. I have a batch file i.e test.exe where i have written a script to start a Jboss as a service..

**cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\empl\jboss7\bin"**

**service install**

**ECHO "Jboss Starting......."**

**service start**

**TIMEOUT /T 20**

**ECHO "Jboss Started**

and even i tried **NET START "JBAS70SVC"** where JBAS70SVC is service name .

I'm able to install service but when i check status of my service in **SERVICES** folder of windows 7 its not started
When i reboot my system then i can see status **"STARTED"** and my application runs.
how can i start my service without rebooting the system ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SC START Service
```

See SC /?
I need to add these chars to reach min post requirements :)